# How to remove \n from a json file

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

when I try to save the scraped data inside a json file using terminal there is a \n after Brand and Brand name ({"Brand": "\n   Libra\n  ", "Price": "$24.95"},).
How to solve this problem.

```
import scrapy


class GlassSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'glass'
    allowed_domains = ['www.glassesshop.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.glassesshop.com/bestsellers/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.xpath("//div[@class='col-12 pb-5 mb-lg-3 col-lg-4 product-list-row text-center product-list-item']"):
            yield {
                'Brand': item.xpath(".//div[@class='p-title']/a/text()").get(),
                'Price': item.xpath(".//div[@class='product-title p-tab p-tab-13145']/span/text()").get()
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str` `replace` method:

```py
...
    yield {
        'Brand': item.xpath(".//div[@class='p-title']/a/text()").get("").replace("\n",""),
        'Price': item.xpath(".//div[@class='product-title p-tab p-tab-13145']/span/text()").get("").replace("\n","")
        }
```